# Writing numbers comma separated in JSON

Tags: modern-experience, json, json-formatting, column-formatting, currency-field

Following a tutorial: [SharePoint modern view formatting with JSON](https://collab365.community/sharepoint-modern-view-formatting-json-part-1-2/) 
I realized that formatting a column with numeric or currency values are shown like *strings*. In this case I have the *"Price"* column with a **Currency** value format, it's supposed to be showed like this (notice is separated with commas):

[image]

but after the JSON formatting, it is shown like this:

[image]

I want the values to be comma separated.
This is the JSON part where I use the *"Price"* value:

```
{
    "elmType": "span",
    "txtContent": "Price",
    "style": {
      "display": "block",
      "padding-top": "20px"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "class": "ms-fontSize-l ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary"
    }
},
{
    "elmType": "span",
    "txtContent": "='$' +[$Price]",
    "style": {
      "display": "block"
    }
},
```

How can I make the value to be shown as numeric (with commas) and not like a string?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no built-in function currently to apply a number format.  You might be able to do some trickery by converting it toString, then looping through the "characters" and inserting a comma every every third character, but that sounds painful just to format the number